# Trait or method that does not depend on generic type

Tags: generics, rust, traits, type-traits

I have a generic structure in rust that has one general field, in this case **val** and a type specific field:

```
struct A<T> {
    val: i32,
    t: T
}
```

What I am trying to do is to have a method associated to the struct regardless the type **T**. Something that I can call like this:

```
A::my_method()
```

Instead of:

```
A::<T>::my_method()
```

I tried implementing a trait called **Get** on **A<T>** and call it as follows:

```
struct A<T> {
    val: i32,
    t: T
}

trait Get {
    type ValType;
    fn get_val() -> Self::ValType;
}

impl<T> Get for A<T> {
    type ValType = i32;
    
    fn get_val() -> Self::ValType {
        2
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {
        val: 2,
        t: 3.0
    };
    
    // This is the call I want, if possible
    println!("{:?}", A::get_val());
}
```

The issue is that it doesn't compile, which is to be expected. The outcome I want is something like this:

```
impl<T> Get for A<any T> {
    type ValType = i32;
    
    fn get_val() -> Self::ValType {
        2
    }
}
```

I found on some posts that a workaround is to have a dummy type parameter and call my function as this:

```
struct DummyType;

fn main() {
    let a = A {
        val: 2,
        t: 3.0
    };
    
    // This is the call I want, if possible
    println!("{:?}", A::<DummyType>::get_val());
}
```

Comment: This seems like a weird problem to have. Is the goal really just to be able to elide the turbofish, or is there something deeper?

Comment: What you've implemented is an associated function, not a method. If your goal is a method, see Jakub's answer below

Comment: I am looking for an associated function, like mentioned by @BallpointBen, to ellide the turbofish. In the current setup I might be required to create one, or more, dummy types in order to do what I want which I do not find particular clean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your design looks wrong. If the type is generic, what does it mean to have a non-generic method?

Anyway, you can use a sentinel type (and you don't need a trait for that, I don't really get why you put it in the first place):

```rust
impl A<()> {
    fn get_val() -> i32 {
        2
    }
}
```

The compiler infers `T` to be `()` automatically when you call `A::get_val()`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=542eee3f2f5eae9845a4a5059f150cbe).

Answer (score 2):

What you are probably missing is a method receiver.

```rust
pub struct A<T> {
    pub field: usize,
    pub something: T,
}

pub trait Getter {
    type Output;
    fn get(&self) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<T> Getter for A<T> {
    type Output = usize;
    fn get(&self) -> Self::Output {
        self.field
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A { field: 10, something: 3.0 };
    assert_eq!(a.get(), 10);
}
```

Here you can return the state of `A` and not just constant.

Comment: I have tried with the receiver before posting the question and indeed it works (my apologies for not mentioning it). My goal is to have it called without receiver, in other words to ellide the turbo fish operator

Answer (score 1):

Fine, I tried this and rust seems to be okay with it:

```
pub trait Get {
    type Output;
    fn get() -> Self::Output;
}

pub struct A<T>(T);

impl Get for A<()> {
    type Output = usize;
    fn get() -> Self::Output {
        2
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", A::get());
}
```

The `()` is the best pick here as you want to express that parameter is not important to us here but also not declare a type just for that.